Alternate Flush Right Left in the text block
With this minimal example, the argument (text) of the \position command is placed inside a \marginpar. I would like to have the text of \position within the text block and NOT in the margin. \marginpar  approximates what I'm aiming to do, which is to have the text of \position placed towards the outer margin of the page within the text block, but not in the margin, so that it will alternate with the recto and verso pages for the fore-edge of the page. How can I do this?
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{memoir} 
\settypeblocksize{6.5in}{5in}{} 
\setlrmargins{.75in}{}{1.5} 
\setulmargins{.75in}{}{} 
\checkandfixthelayout 
\pagestyle{plain} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\newcommand{\position}[1]{\marginpar{\textcolor{red}{\MakeLowercase{\scshape #1}}}} 
\setmarginnotes{.5em}{5em}{2ex} 
\marginparmargin{outer} 
\begin{document} 
\position{Stand} 
\lipsum[2-7] 
\position{Sit} 
\lipsum[10] 
\end{document}


\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{memoir}
\settypeblocksize{6.5in}{5in}{}
\setlrmargins{.75in}{}{1.5}
\setulmargins{.75in}{}{}
\checkandfixthelayout
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\position}[1]{\marginpar{\textcolor{red}{\MakeLowercase{\scshape #1}}}}
\setmarginnotes{.5em}{5em}{2ex}
\marginparmargin{outer}
\begin{document}
\position{Stand}
\lipsum[2-7]
\position{Sit}
\lipsum[10]
\end{document}

Welcome to the site.  You can "edit" your question and paste in your example code.  If you then highlight that code and hit the { } icon, it adds 4 blank spaces to the beginning of each line, which renders the code as code and not text.

The instruction \setlrmargins{.75in}{}{1.5} generates the following error message: Class memoir Error: The combination of argument values is ambiguous. The lengths will be set to zero. Please fix.

to insert within the text block use wrapfig package, not marginpars
